# How to call simple web-service in c# and show response in text-box?

Tags: c#, php

Today is my first day at c#. I want to call simple web-service from c# desktop application. I searched over net but could not found any simple example in this regard. Can anyone please help me to start this job from ABC. I have web-service as
echo.php( placed in htdocs folder of xampp)

```
<?php
    echo "Hello";    
?>
```

and want to call it on button press

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //   want to call web-service from here and want to print response in   
    //   any text box.                
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous methods to do this in C#, For your simple example, a [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx)-Call should do what you want.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var response = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:8000"); // or whatever your url might look like

    myTextBox.Text = response;
}
```

Comment: No problem at all! If this solves your issue, it would be nice if you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ;)

Comment: oh . . yeh sure . . .actually i tried it earlier but it let me wait to accept the answer for 4 mins. . . :D

Comment: No worries at all. glad I could help